# Does the cell phone model affect the arrival time of SMS

Tags: wireless, mobile

I am developing an SMS based system, and I was asked if the cell phone model has a significant effect on the arrival time of the SMS. Although, I'm a bit sure it doesn't because of my testing.

I have tested my system on different phone models, from old phones to smart phones, and the SMS arrives on time almost instantly. Although, it would still be nice to have some real proof if it affects, or not, the arrival time.

I googled this, but it just resulted in how cell phone and SMS work.

Comment: When SMS messages are delivered depends on the carrier, not the device to which the messages are delivered.

Comment: So the antenna inside the phone does not affect the sms receiving? Do you have any references you can give. So that i can read it. Thanks. :)

Comment: When a cell tower sends something to a phone, the phone gets it right away. The antenna is layer-1, but the message is in an upper-layer. Does the antenna type affect how soon voice traffic is sent to the phone? No. That could cause a delay in the conversation on the handset. The real source of delays are in the carrier(s), and/or PSTN, network(s).

Comment: Thank you ron. You can post an answer so that i will accept it. It would be great if you can give me a link to read more about this stuff concerning the antenna of the phone

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

In practice. If operator deliver SMS only over GSM network, but not over 3G network and support 3G for data transfer. Some 3G phones connect only by "better" 3G protocol and cant recieve sms quickly. Until it switch to lover protocol because of low signal or no 3G coverage.

Possible it related with operator network misconfiguration or bug in phone software or both in combination.

Answer (score 1):

When SMS messages are delivered depends on the carrier, not the device to which the messages are delivered. When a cell tower sends something to a phone, the phone gets it right away. The antenna is layer-1, but the message is in an upper-layer. Does the antenna type affect how soon voice traffic is sent to the phone? No. That could cause a delay in the conversation on the handset. The real source of delays are in the carrier(s), and/or PSTN, network(s).